# Using DNS for redirect naked domain with path

Tags: redirect, dns

In my DNS provider I set to redirect the naked domain:

```
http://mydomain.com to http://www.otherdomain.com/index.html
```

Redirect works, however I need to pass the `path` also to `index.html` to whatever means, what could be the solution?

**Example:**

Pass the path 'abc' to index.html

```
http://mydomain.com/abc
```

The `abc` will be passed into the `index.html` hosted in otherdomain.com, how can this be done? Or the path during a redirect is lost in translation already?

**Update:**

As per my understanding DNS providers usually does this through pointing the naked domain into a site where it will do the 301 redirect, where it should still have the path and subfolder in the original request, I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS simply resolves the domain name to an IP. If the domain name requested by the browser is on the web server then the web server will return whichever file is appropriate for the request. An example would be a VHOST in Apache. The DNS server doesn't look up anything relating to the actual files on the URL itself other than the domain name.

To handle this with Apache you might setup the server like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mydomain.com
  ServerAlias otherdomain.com

  Redirect / http://www.otherdomain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```